# Preventing output of extra compiler files

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

When I compile a document with *PdfLaTeX + View PDF* quick build command option selected, Texmaker outputs these files in the same directory with the .tex file:

```
MyDoc.aux
MyDoc.log
MyDoc.pdf
MyDoc.synctex.gz
```

Among these files I only need the PDF file. The other compiler output files my be important for debugging or for some other purposes, but as a standard user I find them as nothing but garbage. How do I disable generation of these other three files?

Comment: You can't disable the generation. You can put the files in an extra directory or you can remove the files after compiling.

Comment: If you want your cross references to work (and tables of contents, index etc) those files are not garbage, they are where the information latex needs is stored.

Comment: There is an option in `Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Commands`. There you have a checkbox labeled: `'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files'`. This will mean that the output PDF file will also go there. I don't know of any finer grained control as to where the different files should go.